Django Models - trying to get the "best of both worlds" when it comes to copying a model vs subclassing it
Let's say I have a base class (Django model) called Character that looks something like
class Character(models.Model):
    strength = models.blabla
    dex = models.blabla
    ...

I can set that up with its attributes and hook it up to Admin and everything is lovely.
Then I decide I want a NonPlayerCharacter model, which has everything the Character model has, plus a new field or two.  I can think of at least two ways to do this, each with pros and cons.
Option 1:
# The basic obvious stupid-simple answer is just to copy the model and add the fields

class NonPlayerCharacter(models.Model):
    strength = models.blabla
    dex = models.blabla
    ...
    faction = models.blabla

Pros: Everything is kept very simple and easy to manage, and if the models need to diverge in the future, that's easy too.
Cons:  Obvious code duplication and keeping universal changes in sync.  If I change a stat or add a method on one, I've got to duplicate it on the other.  If I add another type of Character, like Mob, well then it triples the upkeep to keep the necessary parts in sync.
Option 2:
# The next most obvious solution is to subclass Character

class NonPlayerCharacter(Character):
    faction = models.blabla

Pros:  I don't have to worry about keeping my classes in sync if I add something or make a change.  Each is only concerned with its own NEW attributes and methods.
Cons:  Everywhere I query for Character will also, by default, pull every subclass of Character.  I'm (somewhat) aware of how to filter that out on a query-by-query basis, but it sure would be nice if Character.objects just got me characters and left the rest to queries for that particular model/subclass.
Is there a handy method to get the best of both worlds without filtering Character each time, or am I just asking something unreasonable?

Use an abstract base model?

I'm... not sure why I didn't think of that.  It's probably the answer.

For the benefit of anyone reading this in the future who may need clarification - If both Char and NPC just inherit from a CharBase or something, then my Char queries will give me chars, NPC queries will give me npcs, and all the shared attributes will still be there from the base

Typically you can make an abstract base model, like:
class BaseCharacter(models.Model):
    strength = models.blabla
    dex = models.blabla
    …

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Character(BaseCharacter):
    pass


class NonPlayerCharacter(BaseCharacter):
    faction = models.blabla

This is totally correct, and I should have thought of it at some point hah.  Though the "abstract" flag is new to me and very useful as well so thank you!
